# The name of the job cannot be blank. (SqlManagerUI)

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, jobs

I had filled all the parameters but it doesn't let me save my job because this error occurs.
I specified a job name in general mode but it shows this error again.

```
The name of the job cannot be blank. (SqlManagerUI)

Program Location:

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.JobPropertySheet.DoPreProcessExecution(RunType runType, ExecutionMode& executionResult)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.SqlMgmtTreeViewControl.DoPreProcessExecutionAndRunViews(RunType runType)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.SqlMgmtTreeViewControl.ExecuteForSql(PreProcessExecutionInfo executionInfo, ExecutionMode& executionResult)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.SqlMgmtTreeViewControl.Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.IExecutionAwareSqlControlCollection.PreProcessExecution(PreProcessExecutionInfo executionInfo, ExecutionMode& executionResult)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.ViewSwitcherControlsManager.RunNow(RunType runType, Object sender)
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you creating the job on the same version of SQL that the server is running?

I have had something like this before when creating the job on my development PC. To fix the problem I RDP'd to the SQL Server and created the job on the server without any problem.

Phil